# Map a layout onto memory address

Tags: c++, memory, struct

In C++ is there a way to "map" my desired layout onto a memory data, **without** memcopying it?

I.e. there is a `void* buffer`, and I know its layout:

- byte1: uint8_t
- byte2-3: uint16_t
- byte4: uint8_t

I know I can create a struct, and memcpy the data to the struct, and then I can have the values as fields of struct.

But is there a way achieving this without copying? The data is already there, I just need to get some fields, and I'm looking a way for something can help with the layout.

(I can have some `static int`s for the memory offsets, but I'm hoping for some more generic).

I.e: I would have more "layouts", and based on type of the raw data I'd map the appropriate layout and access its fields which still points to the original data.

I know I can point structs to data, it is easy:

```
struct message {
    uint8_t type;
};
struct request:message {
    uint8_t rid;
    uint8_t other;
};
struct response:message {
    uint8_t result;
};

vector<uint8_t> data;
data.push_back(1); //type
data.push_back(10);
data.push_back(11);
data.push_back(12);
data.push_back(13);

struct request* ptrRequest;

ptrRequest = (struct request*)&data[1];
cout << (int)ptrRequest->rid; //10
cout << (int)ptrRequest->other; //11
```

But what I'd like to achieve is to have a map with the layouts, i.e:

```
map<int, struct message*> messagetypes;
```

But I have no clue on how can I proceed as emplacing would need a new object, and casting is also challenging if the maps stores the base pointers only.

Comment: I'm not sure about the strict-aliasing rules here, but if the structure is packed properly then you could just cast it to a pointer to the structure.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Casting a pointer to the structure is currently UB: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p0593r6.html#objects-provided-as-byte-representation

Answer (score 2):

> In C++ is there a way to "map" my desired layout onto a memory data, without memcopying it?

No, not in standard C++.

If the layout matches that of the class<sup>1</sup>, then what you might be able to do is to write the memory data onto the class instance initially, so that it doesn't need for copying afterwards.

If the above is not possible, then what you might do is copy (yes, this is memcopy, but hold that thought) the data onto an automatic instance of the class, then placement-new a copy of the automatic instance onto the source array. A good optimiser can see that these copies back and forth do not change the value, and can optimise them away. Matching layout is also necessary here. Example:

```
struct data {
    std::uint8_t  byte;
    std::uint8_t  another;
    std::uint16_t properly_aligned;
};

void* buffer = get_some_buffer();
if (!std::align(alignof(data), sizeof(data), buffer, space))
    throw std::invalid_argument("bad alignment");

data local{};
std::memcpy(&local, buffer, sizeof local);
data* dataptr = new(buffer) data{local};
std::uint16_t value_from_offset = dataptr->properly_aligned;
```

https://godbolt.org/z/uvrXS2 Notice how there is no call to `std::memcpy` in the generated assembly.

One thing to consider here is that the multi-byte integers must have the same byte order as the CPU uses natively. Therefore the data is not portable across systems (of different byte endienness). More advanced de-serialisation is required for portability.

---

<sup>1</sup> It however seems unlikely that the data could possibly match the layout of the class, because the second element which is `uint16_t` is not aligned to two a 16 bit boundary from start of the layout.

Comment: Could you show me an example for the automatic instance thing please? I'd need different classes (or structs) based on type.

Comment: @Daniel added example.

Answer (score 2):

If your layout structure is POD you can do placement *new-expression* with no initialization, that serves as an object creation marker. E.g.:

```
#include <new> // Placement new.
// ...
uint8_t* data = ...; // Read from disk, network, or elsewhere.
static_assert(std::is_pod<request>::value, "struct request must be POD.");
request* ptrRequest = new (static_cast<void*>(data)) request;
```

That only works with PODs. This is a long-standing issue documented in [P0593R6
Implicit creation of objects for low-level object manipulation](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p0593r6.html#objects-provided-as-byte-representation).

If your target architecture requires data to be aligned, add `data` pointer alignment check.

---

As another answer states, `memcpy` may be eliminated by the compiler, examine the assembly output.